# Refer to an object being initialized within the initialization?

Tags: c#, syntax, initialization

I have an object DataParameterInfo (DPI) with a couple of delegate methods that are used to move data from a DataReader into a POCO or to get values out of the POCO.

Example:

```
new DataParameterInfo<IBulletinPCN>
{
    FieldName = "ChangeProcedure",
    ParameterName = "@ChangeProcedure",
    EntityName = "ChangeProcedure",
    DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    FieldType = FieldType.Other,
    PopulateEntity = (dr, e) => e.ChangeProcedure = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("ChangeProcedure")) ? null : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("ChangeProcedure")),
    ReadEntity = e => e.ChangeProcedure
}
```

I would *like* to refer to the Fieldname property of my DPI within the PopulateEntity delegate like such:

```
    PopulateEntity = (dr, e) => e.ChangeProcedure = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(FieldName)) ? null : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal(FieldName)),
```

or maybe

```
    PopulateEntity = (dr, e) => e.ChangeProcedure = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(this.FieldName)) ? null : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal(this.FieldName)),
```

Only the "this" when I try that refers to the class in which the DPI is being created, not the DPI itself.

Can I do what I'm trying, above, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the fieldname to your delegate as a parameter by changing the caller of that delegate:

ex:

```
PopulateEntity = (dr, e, fieldname) => e.ChangeProcedure = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldname)) ? null : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal(fieldname))
```

and in the point where you execute that delegate you say:

```
PopulateEntity(dr, e, this.fieldname);
```

Comment: *facepalm* I don't know how I missed this possibility.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to another member of a class withtin an object initializer for that class - this would lead to circular references.

You can get around this by simply assigning your `PopulateEntity` property *after* the initializer.

Comment: Hmm.  Yeah ok I can see that.  The DPI's are created as part of a list in a static property, but I could rework that so the property is populated by a method and then walk the list after... but then that would make accessing the entity properties tricky unless I wrote each one manually and I'm trying to make this less manual overall... still, its a good lead.

Answer (score 0):

The `var x = new Foo { property = bar }` is just a short hand way of doing the old `var x = new Foo();  x.property=bar;`  For this scenario, you'll just have to do it the old fashioned way where there's no problem referencing previously set property values.